# JPEG is not connected in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, jpg, world-imagery

When manually creating a World Image (JPEG) repository in GeoServer 2.15.5-2.21.1, I get an error:

> Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: Failed to create reader from file://G:\GeoServer\data\Upload\Demo\test_rm_jpg_wgs.jpg and hints Hints: REPOSITORY = org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogRepository@3fa62510 EXECUTOR_SERVICE = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@4b65fde5[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0] System defaults: FEATURE_FACTORY = org.geotools.feature.LenientFeatureFactoryImpl@4b0561ee COMPARISON_TOLERANCE = 1.0E-8 FILTER_FACTORY = FilterFactoryImpl FORCE_AXIS_ORDER_HONORING = http GRID_COVERAGE_FACTORY = GridCoverageFactory TILE_ENCODING = null STYLE_FACTORY = StyleFactoryImpl LENIENT_DATUM_SHIFT = true FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER = true

When creating a World Image (JPEG) repository using the REST API, an error occurred:

> Failed to create reader from file://G:\GeoServer\data\Upload\Demo\test_rm_jpGGGGGG_wgs.jpg and hints Hints: FEATURE_FACTORY = org.geotools.feature.LenientFeatureFactoryImpl@4b0561ee COMPARISON_TOLERANCE = 1.0E-8 FILTER_FACTORY = FilterFactoryImpl FORCE_AXIS_ORDER_HONORING = http GRID_COVERAGE_FACTORY = GridCoverageFactory TILE_ENCODING = null STYLE_FACTORY = StyleFactoryImpl REPOSITORY = org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogRepository@3fa62510 LENIENT_DATUM_SHIFT = true FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER = true EXECUTOR_SERVICE = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@4b65fde5[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]

Files I'm trying to connect: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/U-ATedTq4MRT2w

The files are unloaded from ArcGIS. In QGIS, they open perfectly.

Do I need to save JPEG in a special way so that GeoServer can read it?
Can you tell me what the problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your world file has `,` instead of `.` as the decimal points. Once you fix that it loads fine for me.

I'm not sure if world files are supposed to follow your locale, if you think they should then you'll need to file an enhancement request.